# TypeError: pokemon.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, frontend

I've just started to learn react, I am trying to build a react app with the pokemon api and got the following error: `TypeError: pokemon.map is not a function`, I am not sure why the .map is not a function in js, does it have something to do with my extensions or the code below? Please help, thank you in advance!

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PokemonList from './PokemonList'


function App() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState("pokemon-1", "pokemon-2")
  return (
    <PokemonList pokemon={pokemon}/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**PokemonList.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function PokemonList ({pokemon}) {
  return (
    <div>
    {pokemon.map(p =>(
      <div key={p}>{p}</div>
    ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Pagination.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Pagination() {
  return (
    <>

    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize the state as array, `useState(["pokemon-1", "pokemon-2"])`

Comment: @naortor yes, it works now! does it mean we need to store the pokemon in an array?

Comment: `pokemon.map` is a function on arrays, so if you are using map, pokemon should be an array.

Comment: @naortor thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to make the default value of the `pokemon` be an array
`const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState(["pokemon-1", "pokemon-2"])`

Notice the square brackets around the two string values `["pokemon-1", "pokemon-2"]`